# Setting a constraint with dynamic trailing

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I am trying to set a trailing constraint that changes based on screen size. Here's the example. Do I have to set a certain priority with >=?

What I want is for the plus button's trailing space to always be the same distance no matter the screen size. How do I set this constraint?

[image]
[image]

Comment: edited my question, does that clear it up? @TimeString

Comment: In your question you're asking for a constraint that changes based on screen size but is also constant...

Comment: Correct, I would like to have it dynamic @ABakerSmith

Comment: I'm just confused as to how something can be constant and variable at the same time?

Comment: A trailing space to the right side will always be whatever constant you make it. It doesn't change with the size of the screen. Is that what you want?

Comment: Okay I'm pretty confused too. How do I make my button always pinned with the same distance no matter the screen size?

Comment: Just control drag from the button to the right side of the superview, and choose "trailing space to container"

Comment: Isn't that what I have done? When I adjust to 4.7 in the button stays where it would be on a 4-in @rdelmar

Comment: I have no idea what you've done. Did you add a trailing constraint?

Comment: Yes I have, sorry, I thought my pictures were a sufficient amount of info @rdelmar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74453/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-andy).

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'll try to answer but I might be wrong since I might miss some information. For me there are two important components, the right most button (with a white cross in the middle) and all the other objects in the left. I assume other objects are somehow grouped and can be treated as a single unit. What you need to do is add new constraints from the storyboard. For the button, you at least need to add "horizontal space to the right" constraint and "width" constraint. For the left hand side, you need to add "horizontal space to the left" and "horizontal space to the right", but don't fix the width. I think this can achieve the visual effect you want. If it still doesn't work you might want to check this tutorial, http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial, as your question is very fundamental.